# Getting "An error occurred and processing cannot continue" after logging into SSO

Tags: weblogic, single-sign-on, weblogic12c

I have 3 applications deployed on a weblogic server and have enabled SSO for all and are working fine. I have recently added one more application and have enabled SSO for that also.. But after SSO login i am getting "An error occurred and processing cannot continue" message and nothing i see in logs. But if get through SSO authentication using other applications deployed in this server and then open new tab and then access the new application's link, its working fine.

Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of SSO do you have? What security providers do you use? Can you increase logging level to DEBUG and turn on DebugSecurityAtn category?